# if / else in jquery

Tags: jquery

Really struggling with this simple code here. I'm checking if the section with #setactionsuccess exists if not I want to create it and prepend it to the container. First part works smooth but it never goes to 'else' (and the condition is met - I triple checked that). Any help greatly appreciated.

```
if ($('#setactionsuccess')){
    var currenttime = new Date();
    $('#setactionsuccess').empty();
    $('#setactionsuccess').html('<h2>Set successfully deleted</h2><p>Set was successfully removed from this Edition on '+currenttime+'</p>');
} else {
    console.log('here');
    var string = '<section class="successful" id="setactionsuccess"><h2>Set successfully deleted</h2><p>Set was successfully removed from this Edition on '+currenttime+'</p></section>';
    console.log(string);
    $('#currentsets').prepend(string);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ($('#setactionsuccess'))` always returns true
because javascript cheks for `null` and `undefined` and jquery never returns a `null` or `undefine`d even when any element with id setactionsuccess dosent exists
try looking for length for the selector `$('#setactionsuccess').length`

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. That's useful to know

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
if($('#setactionsuccess').length > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get always something from a selector even if there are no matches. You hav to check the number of matches against 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element exists by using `length`

```
if($('#setactionsuccess').length) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have block with id `#setactionsuccess` and you need to check, if it is empty, that is correct solution:

```
if ($('#setactionsuccess'.text().length != 0)){
    var currenttime = new Date();
    $('#setactionsuccess').empty();
    $('#setactionsuccess').html('<h2>Set successfully deleted</h2><p>Set was successfully removed from this Edition on '+currenttime+'</p>');
} else {
    console.log('here');
    var string = '<section class="successful" id="setactionsuccess"><h2>Set successfully deleted</h2><p>Set was successfully removed from this Edition on '+currenttime+'</p></section>';
    console.log(string);
    $('#currentsets').prepend(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(selector).length)
```

You can check by this code.